# Max amount of tweets returned by the statuses/filter endpoint (streaming API)

Tags: twitter, streaming, limit

I'm positive there was a limit of 1% of the whole firehose.
But now I can't find any mention to it in the official documentation.
Did they remove it?
There is a mention in the sample endpoint, but it's not what I'm looking for: I'm specifically talking of the statuses/filter endpoint.

Any clue?

Comment: the free filter stream is levelled at 1% of the firehose, this is correct.

Comment: Thank you @AndyPiper, I'm sure it's like that. But my question was: Did they remove the mention to this limitation from the official documentation? Can you point me to a link where it is clearly stated? Thank you

Comment: Excellent question! No, I just don't think we ever directly stated it in the dev docs from the start (bad). I can point you to an announcement we made about this a while ago that clarifies this https://twittercommunity.com/t/potential-adjustments-to-streaming-api-sample-volumes/31628

Comment: Note that statuses/filter will be replaced by the new (currently Twitter Developer Labs) filtered stream API in the future. This may have different parameters and limitations. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter